# Is catur vyuha mentioned in puranas?

Tags: mahabharata, vishnu, puranas, sri-vaishnava

Is catur vyuha of Vishnu mentioned in puranas and Mahabharata?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, chatur vyuhas are mentioned in [Mahabharata: Santi Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12c039.htm):

> He who is the eternal Supreme Soul and is known by the name of **Vasudeva**. ... There is nothing among mobile and immobile things in the universe that is immutable, except Vasudeva, the eternal Purusha. ... That illustrious one, viz., Vasudeva, who is called Kshetrajna, and who is freed from attributes, should, O king of kings, be known as the puissant **Sankarshana**, when he takes birth as Jiva. 2 From Sankarshana arises **Pradyumna** who is called 'He that is born as Mind.' From Pradyumna is He who is Aniruddha. ... From Aniruddha springs Brahma. The latter takes birth from **Aniruddha**'s navel.